# How do I write a function in python

Tags: python, function

i have this script, it reads file(file consists of collected tweets), cleans it, gets frequency distribution and creates plot, but now i can work only with one file, what i need is to create function from it, to be able to pass more files. So i can create dataframe with results of freqdist from more files to plot it

```
f = open(.......)
text = f.read()
text = text.lower()
for p in list(punctuation):
    text = (text.replace(p, ''))

allWords = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
allWordDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords)
stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

allWordExceptStopDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords if w not in stopwords)
mostCommon = allWordExceptStopDist.most_common(25)

frame = pd.DataFrame(mostCommon, columns=['word', 'frequency'])
frame.set_index('word', inplace=True)
print(frame)
histog = frame.plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

thank you very much for any help!

Comment: So you're asking "how do I make a function"? [Here you go](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: basically yes, i somehow cant figure out how to write it in function

Comment: so your problem is to write a function in python, it is nothing to do with file read,dataframe or plot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic explanation of python functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409802/basic-explanation-of-python-functions)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
def readStuff( filename )
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = f.read()
    text = text.lower()
    for p in list(punctuation):
        text = (text.replace(p, ''))

    allWords = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
    allWordDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords)
    stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))

    allWordExceptStopDist = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in allWords if w not in stopwords)
    mostCommon = allWordExceptStopDist.most_common(25)

    frame = pd.DataFrame(mostCommon, columns=['word', 'frequency'])
    frame.set_index('word', inplace=True)
    print(frame)
    histog = frame.plot(kind='barh')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: i think yes, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as correct so people know not to answer your question again :)

Comment: This leaks the file handle, you should use `with open(filename) as f: ...`

Comment: I just took the code above and put it into a function, but @Daenyth is correct. Edited.

Comment: thanks, i`ll try that

Comment: Please don't just dump code. That's not helpful for the asker or future readers.