# How to do multiple python exercises in one file, so that previous code does not affect future code

Tags: python

```
#write a program that prints out all the elements of 
the list
# are less than 5
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 
  89,6,5,3,2,1,7,9]
for x in a:
   if x < 5:
      print(x)

#Ask the user for a string and print out whether this 
 string is a
# palindrome or not.

Print("Input a text!")
txt= input()
if txt == txt[::-1]:
  print("This is a palindrome")
else:
print("This is not a Palindrome")
```

What would I put so that the previous code doesn't affect the future code for these python exercises? am new to python :(

Comment: Just be careful not to use previously assigned variables, or re-assign when needed? Or you can group them into several functions like `def exercise1():`, and then call them in a main chunk, like in `if __name__ == "__main__":` clause.

Comment: You can put each exercise into a [function definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409802/basic-explanation-of-python-functions/32409907) and only call the one of them you want to run. To have them not affect each other, make sure not to use any global variables.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to handle this. First, as mentioned in previous answers, you could use different variable names to isolate ( which would not be a good practice ). Second, create functions for each separate code fragment(I strongly suggest this) so you could make a respective function call when needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could use functions to isolate the code, in such way you use `local` variables and not `globals`, because using global variables will influence other code, witch would be very difficult and counterproductive.